# An issue on the setting of [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I used EF 6 code-first approach in my codes as well as existing database(MSSQL Server 2014), and set  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] attribute for the ID (int type) of an entity. Each time, it invokes an exception with the message that the main key(ID of the entity) can't be null when insert operation executes.

I can't figure out what's the what's the problem DatabaseGenerated attribute .